# How to access solution or project properties in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

In **Visual Studio for Windows**, you could right-click your solution or project and access the properties by clicking *Properties*. There isn't a *Properties* section in *Visual Studio for Mac*- where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click a solution or project and click *Options*:

[image]

The window that opens doesn't exactly mirror the *Properties* window in VS for Windows but it has all of the expected settings.

[image]